# Can anyone explain how to fix this index error

Tags: python, numpy

currently I am using this code to output a 2-D implicit convection diffusion matrix. I cannot figure out how to get the last row of the column to populate. I have it grab all this data from a txt file which has also been included below the code. I then try to use the range values to have it out put a matrix but I cannot seem to get the matrix to output correctly. any help or an explanation as to why it wont work would be great appreciated. when I change the range of i and j to just Nx or Ny I get an error for indexing which I don't quite understand either, however in order to solve this  have set the range to Nx-1 and Ny-1 which I believe to be incorrect. any advice is once again greatly appreciated.

```
import os
import numpy as np
#import data into variables for use

file = open("diffsolverin.txt","r")
line = file.readline() # rea the first line (remove comments from input)
tokens = line.split() # this splits the line into chunks of characters separated by spaces
Nx = int(tokens[0]) # assign the value of the first chunk of characters to Nx after interpreting them as an integer
Ny = int(tokens[1])
width = float(tokens[2])
height = float(tokens[3])
D = float(tokens[4])
t = float(tokens[5])
U_x = float(tokens[6])
U_y = float(tokens[7])
S_p = float(tokens[8])
line = file.readline() # read the second line
tokens = line.split()
left_bc_type = int(tokens[0]) #0 is Dirichlet, 1 is Neumann
right_bc_type = int(tokens[1])
top_bc_type = int(tokens[2])
bottom_bc_type = int(tokens[3])
line = file.readline() # read the third line
tokens = line.split()
left_bc_value = float(tokens[0]) 
right_bc_value = float(tokens[1])
top_bc_value = float(tokens[2])
bottom_bc_value = float(tokens[3])
        
        
N=Nx*Ny
Amat = np.zeros((N,N))
dx = Nx/width
dy = Ny/height
B = np.zeros(N)
phi = np.zeros(N)

       
#solve and establish boundary conditions

for i in range(Nx-1):
   
    for j in range(Ny-1):
        k = (j)*(Ny) + i
        print (k)

        if i == 0:    # this is a left boundary cell, deal with it given the BCs)
            if left_bc_type == 0:
                
                A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                A_w = 0
                A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                Amat[k,k] = A_p
                Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                B[k] = A_p*left_bc_value
            elif left_bc_type == 1:
                
                A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                A_w = 0
                A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                Amat[k,k] = A_p
                Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                B[k] = A_p
        elif i == Nx-1: #this is a right boundary cell, ...
            if right_bc_type == 0:
                
                A_e = 0
                A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
                A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                Amat[k,k] = A_p
                Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                B[k] = A_p*right_bc_value
                
            elif right_bc_type == 1:
                
                A_e = 0
                A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
                A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                Amat[k,k] = A_p
                Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                B[k] = A_p

        elif j == 0:  # this is a top boundary cell
               if top_bc_type == 0:
                   
                   A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                   A_w = D*dy+U_x/2
                   A_n = 0
                   A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                   A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                   Amat[k,k] = A_p
                   Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                   Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                   Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                   B[k] = A_p*top_bc_value
                   
               elif top_bc_type == 1:
                   
                   A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                   A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
                   A_n = 0
                   A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
                   A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                   Amat[k,k] = A_p
                   Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                   Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
                   Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                   B[k] = A_p

        elif j == Ny-1: # this is a bottom boundary cell
               if bottom_bc_type == 0:
                   
                   A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                   A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
                   A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                   A_s = 0
                   A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                   Amat[k,k] = A_p
                   Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                   Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                   Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                   B[k] = A_p*bottom_bc_value
               elif bottom_bc_type == 1:
                   
                   A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
                   A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
                   A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
                   A_s = 0
                   A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
                   Amat[k,k] = A_p
                   Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
                   Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
                   Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
                   B[k] = A_p
        else:
            A_e = D*dx-U_x/2
            A_w = D*dx+U_x/2
            A_n = D*dy+U_y/2
            A_s = D*dy-U_y/2
            A_p = A_e + A_w + A_s + A_n
            Amat[k,k] = A_p
            Amat[k,k+1]=A_e
            Amat[k,k-Nx]=A_n
            Amat[k,k-1]=A_w
            Amat[k,k+Nx]=A_s
            B[k]=A_p
           
print (Amat)
#print(B)
#print (ans)
file = open("diffsolverout.txt", "w+")
filew = str(Amat)
filew1=str(B)
file.write(filew)
file.write(filew1)
file.close()
```

and this is the contents of the text file:

```
10 10 1.0 2.0 0.5 0.1 1 4 1
1 1 1 1
10 10 10 10
```

Once again I either get a blank last row of the matrix which I believe is incorrect or I get an index error for attempting to fill the matrix.

Comment: Could you reduce your code to a minimal working example for reprocuing the error.

Comment: Too long and rambling.  And, when asking about an error, show the FULL TRACEBACK, preferably with just the code necessary to produce it.  Most of us have a 30 second attention span!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. See also ["Can someone help me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

You are reaching outside the boundaries of the matrix, as the error suggests. It is not from the value of `i` or `j` being wrong though. Your boundary cell definitions take `k + Nx` or `k - Nx`, but when you inspect this it is wrong simply because of how indexing works for python.

The error occurs when `k = 90`, and you have `Nx = 10`, so `k + Nx = 90 + 10 = 100`. But the indexing goes from `0-99` not `1-100`. You should just be able to change each of these to be `k + (Nx - 1)` or `k - (Nx - 1)` and fix this specific issue.

You were already able to identify this when saying that `j == Ny - 1`, it is the same logic.

Comment: I changed what you recommended however now i am still not filling out the last row of the matrix. i dont know if its just an error on my part or poor coding. but doing what you recommended only allows my k value to get up to 88 if i get rid of the -1 in each of the ranges this allows me to go higher and possibly fill out the last row however i still am unable to fill it out as i now get the index being to long problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after looking into this more, the way you are indexing the `Amat` is incorrect for what you are trying to do. You have to understand how indexing in a matrix in python (and more generally in maths) works. I thought it deserved a new solution as I wanted to explain it properly.

There are `i` number of rows and `j` number of columns. Your approach is to label each cell in the matrix from left to right, top to bottom with an integer `k`. This is fine and helps out a lot in this approach, but you cannot outright use it to change values in the matrix the way you are. (As a side note, `i` is the rows and `j` is the columns, your approach, while setup to be this way, actually takes `i` as the columns and `j` as the rows when you define `k`)

Imagine that we have `k = 5`. Then in the matrix, we have `A[5,5]` as the point we want to deal with as the central point. To go left or right we get `A[k, k-1]` and `A[k, k+1]`, but to go up or down we have to do `A[k-1,k]` and `A[k+1,k]`.

For your else block (to show all examples) this should actually be:

```
Amat[k, k] = A_p
Amat[k, k + 1] = A_e
Amat[k - 1, k] = A_n
Amat[k, k - 1] = A_w
Amat[k + 1, k] = A_s
```

You'll notice that this just takes `k` as the point of reference but we still need to use the standard way of indexing to reach the values you want, not just add or subtract `Nx` to the cell number. If that makes sense.

Lastly, I just wanted to add a few suggestions to make your code more readable and a lot more debuggable.
The values for `A_e`, `A_w`, `A_n`, `A_s` can be defined just once at the start and then `A_p` can be defined using the required values for the specific case.